# Django populating ChoiceField with attributes from a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

please go easy on me because I am just starting out. I am making an instrument website where people can post their instruments for sale. On the form, I want them to use a drop-down menu that helps facilitate the selection of a category (e.g. trombone, trumpet, saxophone, etc...)

When I use the following code, I get something like this in the dropdown:

---

Category Object
Category Object
Category Object

and these seem to be the correct Category Objects, but what I need is for them to say "Trumpet", "Trombone", "Saxophone" etc. from the database.

***Form***

```
class InventoryForm(forms.Form):
  description = forms.CharField(required=False)
  instrumentCategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=pmod.Category.objects.all())
```

***Model***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    instrumentCategory=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

class Instrument(models.Model):
    description=models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True,null=True)
    instrumentCategory=models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Again, how do I get the dropdown to display the instrument category instead of "Category Object" for each option? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `__unicode__` (`__str__` in python 3) on your models to return what you want to see in the choice list:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    instrumentCategory=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.instrumentCategory
```

This is because Django doesn't automatically know how you want to represent each object.

Check out the `python_to_unicode_compatible` decorator mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! The above code was correct, but I just had to add this onto my model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.instrumentCategory
```

Comment: That's because you're using Python 3, as Robert mentioned in his answer, remember to mark the answer as correct :)